# iOS apps already in App Store and iOS 8 release

Tags: ios, app-store, 64-bit, ios8, xcode6

This is the first time I face a new iOS version release while already having an app in the App Store... Must I have a new version of my app built with Xcode 6 beta and iOS 8 SDK beta and have it ready for sale before the official release of iOS 8? Will Apple remove from the App Store my app if, after the iOS 8 release, I have not submitted a new version built with iOS 8 SDK and iOS 8 users find bugs? I currently have Xcode 5.1.1 and my Xcode project's `Base SDK` set to `Latest iOS`, which is iOS 7.1 in this Xcode version.

And what about 64-bit versions of apps? My app is 32-bit now, will it be mandatory to support 64-bit?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I've another question regarding this: should I submit my app built with Xcode 6 beta before the iOS 8 release date, or should I wait for the iOS 8 and Xcode 6 release?

Answer (score 2):

You should test your app under the iOS 8 betas to determine if there are any issues. If there are then you should address them and have a new version ready to go.

If there are no issues then you don't need to release a new version, but you may want to release a new version that uses new features in iOS 8.

Typically Apple will announce acceptance of apps built against the new release about a week out from the launch date and they ramp up the approval team.  When iOS 7 was released my updated app was reviewed in under 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Apple is the one to decide.

They can decide to accept only submissions/updates with the new SDK at some point in the future - like [they did for iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172013a) - Feb 2014

note, however, that iOS 7 was a complete redesign of the UI, so it makes much more sense to force submissions early.

same goes for the 64bit

I agree with the other answer that advise you to test your app in iOS 8 beta - some apps are buggy there - either because iOS is not complete yet or because there were "breaking changes" (in the UI - for example, the new keyboard).
Also try to build your app with the latest SDK - maybe you don't really need to change a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why should apple remove older versions of the apps after the new iOS 8.0 is released? Apple will not remove it, only you will have to update the app with its newer versions. Before updating the app include 64bit binary before distribution.